# Going into Substitute user

Tags: command-line

I can't seem to be able to type in a password so that I may acquire access to #apt-get. I'm looking to update my system via terminal, but typing out my password does no good to get me into su, as the spaces stay blank, and what I know is the password won't go through. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: sudo pasword  is not visible while typing it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though no characters appear when you type your password, you are actually typing your password.

For security reasons, characters typed in at the password request prompt are not echoed back to the terminal. The characters are there, you just can't see them, that's all.

So type password, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and see.

Comment: I understand that the password doesn't show. When turning on my computer, there's an initial password I need to type in before choosing which user I want to go under. That's the superuser password, right? Well, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Hadi's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433009/going-into-substitute-user/433016#433016) answer you can enable visual feedback when typing passwords by editing your `/etc/sudoers` file and changing the `Defaults` line from:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

to

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

But this is not a good thing because people will get to know the length of your password and it becomes easy to crack it.

[<sub>source</sub>](https://superuser.com/questions/420815/feedback-when-typing-password-at-a-sudo-prompt)